# Regex to extract specific rows containing URLs with Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, regex, conditional-statements

I am trying to extract a list of links from a a web-page that appears as a JSON.  I have tested the regular expression with separate code to assure that it is working, however I am unable to get it to work as part of the subsequent  conditional statement.

The following prints "true" as a boolean if used in the a conditional statement: `System.out.println(Str.matches("\"link\": \"([^\"]+)\","));`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File fout = new File("out.json");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);


        URL a = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=eran+ariel&cx=006156390203515615519%3A-lsrgi-_9-o&key=AIzaSyAeDR4GlES4I2hwAbrifRiF7uUDi12pfaM");
        URLConnection yc = a.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (inputLine.matches("\"link\": \"([^\"]+)\",")) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                bw.write(inputLine);
            } else
                bw.newLine();
        }
        in.close();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Not getting any result.

Comment: I think you want `if (inputLine.matches("\\s*\"link\": \"([^\"]+)\",")) {` or `if (inputLine.trim().matches("\"link\": \"([^\"]+)\",")) {` (because there is indentation and `matches` requires a full string match), but since it is JSON, it is recommended to use JSON dedicated parser to parse it.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor!  
Thank you this has solved the issue. I have evaluated Jaunty as a JSON parser as well.  I appreciate your help, and once again thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having issues using *`Pattern.Matches()`* which require the matching of the whole line,
use a pattern  objects *`Pattern.matcher()`* method which returns a `Match` object from which you
can use its *`Match.find()`* method to find substrings.

Your code will then look like this

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"link\"r\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]+)\",");

 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     Matcher m = p.matcher(inputline);
     if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(inputLine);
         bw.write(inputLine);
     } else
         bw.newLine();
 }
```